# Twitter typeahead

Tags: twitter, typeahead

Question #1:

I have the following code:

```
// NOTE: Initiate auto-complete
  $('#edit-keyword').typeahead({
    remote: '/products/autocomplete.json/%QUERY', 
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }).bind('typeahead:selected', function(object, datum) {
    console.log(object);
  });
```

I return this JSON from the server:

```
1: "Bustello Cafe Coffee Regular"
110: "Barista Prima Coffeehouse Coffee Pods K Cups Darkest Roast French Roast"
713: "Bolthouse Farms Protein Plus Coffee"
5680: "Bustello Cafe Coffee Regular"
5693: "Bustello Cafe Coffee Regular"
```

What do I add to the above code snippet to retreive the ID associated with each item...right now 'datum' only returns the string value.

Question #2:

I just noticed that JSON returns multiple "Bustello Cafe Coffee Regular" with unique ID's but the rendered drop list seems to show only one at a time - I assume there is a supress duplicates in the typeahead control? Where is it???

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `typeahead:selected` and `typeahead:autocompleted` custom events to get at the  `ID` associated with each item if you want, but your json needs an appropriate `ID` property.. for example:

```
[{"ID":111, "Name":"blah"},{"ID":222, "Name":"buuu"}]
```

Something like this using jquery and typeahead:

```
    $("#edit-keyword").on("typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted",
        function(e, datum) {
            // datum containts datum.ID here, do what you want with it
            //.. i.e. assign to a hidden input or knockout observable, etc.
        }
    );
```

As for your duplicates question, I haven't seen a configuration for it, typeahead will attempt to transform your data into typeahead datums if they aren't already, so it might be the `_transformDatum` function in typeahead doing that.

I would suggest that you try structuring your data as a typeahead datum yourself to avoid this and see what happens, see https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#datum for how they are usually structured, in your case the value would be an `object` and you would need to specify the appropriate `valueKey` property.